# How to pg_dump from old version of postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm really scratching my head. I was under the impression that newer versions of pg_dump can export from older versions. However, I keep getting this error:

```
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: detail: server version: 8.0.2; pg_dump version: 16.2
```

I'm exporting from a running RDS instance using a local install of Postgres on Macos. I tried and failed to locate an old version of pg_dump (compilable for Macos, only found windows).

Is this version just *too* old? Or maybe the semantic versioning parser is broken and it thinks 16.2 < 8.0.2?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL version 8.0.2 was [released](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-802-released-303/) on 2005-04-11. The oldest [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-versions.html) AWS RDS PostgreSQL is 9.6 (deprecated).

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) for `pg_dump` from the current PostgreSQL 16 says that "servers back to version 9.2 are supported". [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html) for `pg_dump` from the oldest currently supported PostgreSQL 12 says that "servers back to version 8.0 are supported".

You can run `pg_dump` from PostgreSQL 12 with the docker command:

`docker run postgres:12 pg_dump --version`